# How can i instantiate empty gameobject to be position to existing already gameobject?

Tags: unity, c#

When i click on keyboards for example dfrg i want that if i click on space it will add empty gameobject right after the letter g like a space for example: drg hello So there is a space after the letter g and before the hello I want that the empty gameobject will be like space. So if i click space it should be always position after the clone. But not sure how to do it.
The problem is that i instantiate the clone object after if i click on space key. And i also want the space to work for both side/cases if i first click on space before i clicked and did any clones it should be for example: dfrg There are many spaces before the dfrg

```
using System.Collections;
 using System.Collections.Generic;
 using System.IO;
 using System.Linq;
 using UnityEngine;

 public class Test : MonoBehaviour
 {
     public GameObject[] prefabs;
     public int gap = 50;
     public int offset = 0;

     private GameObject go;

     void Start()
     {
         prefabs = Resources.LoadAll("Prefabs", typeof(GameObject)).Cast<GameObject>().ToArray();

         foreach (GameObject prefab in prefabs)
         {
             if (prefab.name == "testing")
             {
                 go = prefab;
             }
         }
     }

     void Update()
     {
         if (Input.anyKey)
         {
             if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.Space))
             {

             }
             foreach (Transform child in go.transform)
             {
                 if (Input.inputString == child.name)
                 {
                     Transform clone = Instantiate(child);
                     clone.parent = transform;

                     clone.transform.eulerAngles = new Vector3(0, 0, 0);
                     offset += gap;
                     clone.transform.position = new Vector3(-offset, 0, 0);
                 }
             }
         }
     }
 }
```

Comment: Is this related to [this other question](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/150130/when-i-position-gameobjects-using-keys-the-gameobjects-rotation-is-wrong-and-the)?